# Positioning an element relative to parent vertically, but relative to viewport horizontally

Tags: css

[image: Popover]

I have this UI element that opens a tooltip/popover thing when clicked. I would like the tooltip window to appear right below the UI element, but on mobile it should be aligned to the left and right side of the viewport instead of being centered under the "more…" button.

In other words, I would like to have:

```css
.tooltip {
 top: 100%; // appear right below the button
 left: 10px; // 10px *from the edge of the window*
}
```

Is there a way to mix referentials like this? Have the `top` position be calculated based on a parent, while `left` and `right` are calculated based on the viewport?

(by the way I know I can do this with JavaScript but I wanted to look for a pure CSS solution first)

Comment: How about using css media queries to style the tooltip independently in device sizes? Javascript might be full proof solution for your tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have so far is to make sure that the parent that has `position: relative` and acts at the referential for the absolutely positioned tooltip spans the whole width of the viewport. This works but it means the tooltip can't just be a drop-in component that can be added anywhere in your app, which is what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible with an extra parent element around the tooltip to position it vertically.

Working demo: https://codepen.io/paweldecowski/pen/vYXaXvN

```html
<span>Anchor
  <div class="tooltip-parent">
    <div class="tooltip">Tooltip</div>
  </div>
</span>
```

```css
.tooltip-parent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.tooltip {
  left: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Edit:

Actually, this will work without the parent element, too. Just position the tooltip absolutely:

```css
.tooltip {
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

The tooltip will by default stick to the bottom of the anchor. Of course, you won’t be able to use `top` or `bottom` properties because they will be relative to the viewport, but you can adjust the vertical position with `margin`.